# How can I improve Typescript caching?

Tags: typescript, performance

I have a very complex type in Typescript, and it's taking ~3-5 seconds to give me suggestions on its properties or functions.

If I access the same complex object two lines in a row, it'll take 3-5 seconds each time (even though the object hasn't changed and all the same suggestions are valid).

**How can modify TS to cache type definitions, rather than trying to build them from scratch over and over again?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically (all three times I've seen it), this level of complexity in typing is due to recursion (O^n strikes again).

There is no way I could find of making TS do better caching aside from modifying the project itself.

As an alternative, flatten everything.  You may end up with less correct types from it, but take everything recursive than can be more like an array and make it so.

Hope this helps someone.